# Nested lists - Remove given element within nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

We have the following list as input:

```
[[-5, -1], [1, -5], [5, -1]]
```

I have created a function which takes `clist` as a list and `number` a random number that I want to remove from the list.

The function should remove all the nested lists that contain the given `number` and remove the **negative** `number` within the nested list

```
def reduce(self, clist, number):
    self.temp = list(clist)

    # remove the nested list that contain the given number
    for item in clist:
        if number in item:
            self.temp.remove(item)

    # remove the negative number within the nested list
    for obj in self.temp:
        try:
            obj.remove(-number)
        except:
            pass

    return self.temp
```

Let's pick `1` as a `number` and run the code.

- The first `for` loop will remove all nested lists that contain the given number and will get the following:

  `self.temp =  [[-5, -1], [5, -1]]`

  `clist = [[-5, -1], [1, -5], [5, -1]]`
- The second `for` loop should remove all negative `number` within the nested lists but we get the following:

  `self.temp =  [[-5], [5]]`

  `clist = [[-5], [1, -5], [5]]`

What I do not get is why `clist` gets affected when I am working on the second `for` loop, especially when I'm working on `self.temp` list? It should be without reference to the original list, but I am missing something out. Help?

Comment: can you show the complete code for this

Comment: @hsnsd Unfortunately no because it's part of my assignment. But I can tell you other bits that might influence, but so far this is that part that influences my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a nested list comprehension would be easiest:

```
def reduce(clist, number):
    return [[x for x in subl if x != -number] for subl in clist if number not in subl]

print(reduce([[-5, -1], [1, -5], [5, -1]], 1))
# [[-5], [5]]
```

That iterates twice over lists that don't contain `number`, so a slightly more efficient solution would be, though actual speed will depend on your data.

```
def reduce(clist, number):
    result = []
    for subl in clist:
        temp = []
        for x in subl:
            if x == number:
                break
            elif x != -number:
                temp.append(x)
        else:
            result.append(temp)  # Only happens if there was no break
    return result
```

You can save this result to `self.temp` if you want (after adding `self` back to the parameters), but it wasn't clear to me if your actual intention was to save the result to the object or not.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out. It's not necessary to save the result. The one thing I didn't understood is that why when removing an element from ````self.temp```` from the 2nd ````for```` loop, it affects the ````clist```` as well.